# Linear map of unitization of a non-unital $C^\ast$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I recently discussed unitization of a non-unital $C^\ast$-algebra. I proved some facts and so on (which I afterwards found on the internet).

Anyway let's consider the following $C^\ast$-algebra. That is, the
$C^\ast$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ with norm $\|\cdot\|$. Let $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}=\mathcal{A}\oplus \mathbb{C}$ as a vector space. We endow it with multiplication and involution,

$$(a,\lambda)\cdot (b,\mu):=(ab+\lambda b+\mu a,\lambda \mu)$$
and
$$(a,\lambda)^\ast:=(a^\ast,\bar{\lambda})$$

As mentioned I did some proofs of this and discussed with fellow members of this site. However I can see people discuss norm of this beast, let me clarify this.

We consider $\omega:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ by the map $\omega(a):=(a,0)$. This is indeed a two sided ideal $\omega(\mathcal{A})$ and of course also a $\ast$-homomorphism. Now we will suppress the inclusion $\omega$ and think of $\mathcal{A}$ as an ideal in $\mathcal{A}$.

**I claim:** Take $x\in\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ then we consider the linear map $\tilde{L}_x:\tilde{\mathcal{A}}\rightarrow \tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ by $y\mapsto xy$ restricts to a map, $L_x:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ which is bounded with $\|L_x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_1$.

**I want to show the above claim.** Here we know that the one-norm is given by $x=(a,\lambda)\in \tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ by $\|x\|_1=\|a\|+|\lambda|$ and of course $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ denote the operator norm.

But how can we construct such a proof of this claim? I've tried to read more about this kind of unitization and norms on the following link however I don't think they do the claim that I give.

[http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~richard/teaching/s2020/Terasawa.pdf](http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/%7Erichard/teaching/s2020/Terasawa.pdf)

So, how would one do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x=(a,\lambda)\in\bar{\mathcal A}.$ For any $b\in\mathcal A,$
$$\|L_x(b)\|=\|ab+\lambda b\|$$
(by definition of $L_x$) and
$$\begin{align}\|ab+\lambda b\|&\le\|ab\|+\|\lambda b\|\\&\le\|a\|\|b\|+|\lambda|\|b\|\\
&=\|x\|_1\|b\|\end{align}
$$
hence
$$\forall b\in\mathcal A\quad\|L_x(b)\|\le\|x\|_1\|b\|,$$
which is [exactly the definition of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm)
$$\|L_x\|_\infty\le\|x\|_1.$$

Edit: This answers the initial post. Another question has been added meanwhile, which should however be the object of another post.

Comment: Okay thank you Anne, and thanks for clarification. And of course I will avoid “yea”. :) but it could be nice to prove this statement

Comment: I don't understand. Which statement? Do you mean  $\|L_x\|_\infty \leq \|x\|_1$? But it is proved, now, isn't it? So why "it *could be*"?

Comment: Okay I will read and let you know if I have more. Merry Christmas

Comment: Okay back to my first claim for this post. I say that we can take $x\in\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ and so on. I want to show that for $x\in \tilde{\mathcal{A}}$, the linear map $\tilde{L}_x:\tilde{\mathcal{A}}\rightarrow \tilde{\mathcal{A}}$, $y\mapsto xy$ restricts to a map $L_x:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ which is bounded with $\|L_x\|_\infty\leqslant \|x\|_1$:

By your help, we have the norm and so on. But how to show that the linear map  linear map $\tilde{L}_x:\tilde{\mathcal{A}}\rightarrow \tilde{\mathcal{A}}$, $y\mapsto xy$ restricts to a map $L_x:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: $L_x(b)=ab+\lambda b,$ as a particular case of your definition of $L_x.$

Comment: So we did actually prove this. OK. Again thanks for your help, Anne.